# Make a canvas the size of an image?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Im reading a file, checking it's exif data, adding to canvas and transforming if necessary.

I need to keep the canvas the same size as the original image, I've tried this:

```
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
```

This seems to default the canvas size to the default of 300 x 150.

How can I make the canvas the size of the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ctx.canvas.width = img.width
ctx.canvas.height = img.height
```

Should work fine